# R: ggplot - Different Title for each object in a plot list

Tags: r, ggplot2, title

currently I am trying to making a plot list with ggplot from a list of data frames (94 time series). Then I want to export the plots to a PDF. This, so far, was successful using following code:

```
plot.list = lapply(HR_clean, function(x) {
y = length(x)
  z = data.frame("HR" = x, "Time" = rep(1:y, 1))
  ggplot(z, aes(x = Time, y = HR)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_line(linetype = "solid") +
    ggtitle("Plot Title")
    })

ggsave(
  filename = "plots2.pdf", 
  plot = marrangeGrob(plot.list, nrow=1, ncol=1), 
  width = 15, height = 9
)
```

However, I also want that the main title of each plot is equal name of the corresponding list object. Perhaps anyone knows a smart solution for this problem.

Best,
Johnson

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test this (since you are not providing example data) but this should work using `purrr`'s `imap()`:

```
plot.list <- purrr::imap(HR_clean, function(x, name) {
  y <- length(x)
  z <- data.frame("HR" = x, "Time" = rep(1:y, 1))
  ggplot(z, aes(x = Time, y = HR)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_line(linetype = "solid") +
    ggtitle(name)
})
```